# Two mat-errors are displaying at same time

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, angular-forms

These are the mat-errors for password validation in the component(set-pass.component.html)

```
   <mat-form-field >
                <input matInput  placeholder="Confirm password" [type]="hide 
                  ? 'password' : 'text'"  formControlName="confirmPassword" 
               required>

                <mat-error 
           *ngIf="setpassForm.controls.confirmPassword.hasError('required')">
                        Please confirm the password
                </mat-error>
                <mat-error 
          *ngIf="setpassForm.controls.confirmPassword.hasError('matchWith')">
                    Password entries doesn't match
                </mat-error>

   </mat-form-field>
```

This is the .ts(set-pass.component.ts)file

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from 
     '@angular/forms';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { ValidatorUtil } from '../shared/validator.util';

    @Component({
     selector: 'ylb-set-pass',
     templateUrl: './set-pass.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./set-pass.component.css']
   })
   export class SetPassComponent implements OnInit {

       setpassForm: FormGroup;


     constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
          private router: Router) { }

     ngOnInit() {
         this.setpassForm = this.fb.group({
           'code': [null, [Validators.required,]],
           'password': [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), 
              Validators.maxLength(15)]],
           'confirmPassword': [null, [Validators.required, 
              ValidatorUtil.matchWithValidator('password')]],
          });
        }

     onSetpass(){
     this._markAsDirty(this.setpassForm);
      }


       private _markAsDirty(group: FormGroup) {
       group.markAsDirty();
       for (let i in group.controls) {
       group.controls[i].markAsDirty();
      }
    }

  }
```

My issue is that,when i type in password field and leaves confirm password field empty/touched,It has to show only one mat-error i,e (Please confirm the password)

But its's showing 2 mat-errors at the same time.

[image]

Comment: Try  `*ngIf="!setpassForm.controls.confirmPassword.hasError('required') && setpassForm.controls.confirmPassword.hasError('matchWith') "` for match error.

Comment: Its worked,Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check Required Validation on `touch`. Others are fine.

```
<mat-form-field >
    <input matInput  placeholder="Confirm password" [type]="hide 
         ? 'password' : 'text'"  formControlName="confirmPassword" 
                   required>

<mat-error *ngIf="setpassForm.controls.confirmPassword.hasError('required') && setpassForm.get('confirmPassword').touched">
    Please confirm the password
 </mat-error>
<mat-error *ngIf="setpassForm.controls.confirmPassword.hasError('matchWith')">
  Password entries doesn't match
</mat-error>

</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
          <mat-form-field >
                <input matInput  placeholder="Confirm password" [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'"  formControlName="confirmPassword" required>

                <mat-error *ngIf="setpassForm.controls.confirmPassword.hasError('required')">
                        Please confirm the password
                </mat-error>
                <mat-error *ngIf="!setpassForm.controls.confirmPassword.hasError('required') && setpassForm.controls.confirmPassword.hasError('matchWith')">
                    Password entries doesn't match
                </mat-error>

            </mat-form-field>
```

Its working fine,I was forgotten to give !(not) for the 2nd mat-error.

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix, you only have to add the code below to your css file :

```
mat-error {
    display: none;
}

form mat-error:first-child {
    display: block;
}
```

But if you have multiple FormGroups in the same component i recommend you to specify to which form you want to apply the condition by adding formGroup's class name to the css, just like this :

```
.className mat-error {
    display: none;
}

.className form mat-error:first-child {
    display: block;
}
```

To avoid any incoherence between the two forms.